# Swift: Setting StatusBar color on IOS13+ (Using statusBarManager)

Tags: swift, colors, statusbar

I want to define by code the color of my status bar, the way I found it was this one but it is deprecated. Does anyone know what the new way of doing this is? This warning is following me in all my codes

[image]

This code is working but with the warning

The code for whoever wants:

```swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using `UIStatusBarManager` as mention in the warning, you can not also able to set style.

because `statusBarManager` is the get only property. Check [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindowscene/3213943-statusbarmanager)

```
open var statusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { get }
```

You have to override the `preferredStatusBarStyle`

Like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

If you want to change the status bar style to all of your view controllers, you can set it inside the `Info.plist`.

Step 1:
Add `View controller-based status bar appearance` key and set `No` value

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
```

Step 2: Add `Status bar style` key and set style like `Light Content`

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
```

---

---

If you want a different style based on controller then,
Step 1:
Add `View controller-based status bar appearance` key and set `Yes` value

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <true/>
```

Step 2: override `preferredStatusBarStyle` within view controller.

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Here is a good article about [How to set status bar style](https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-set-status-bar-style/).

Comment: Thank you very much for the complete answer! I already knew that I could define it in a single ViewControler. I forgot to comment that I had added the information from step 01, but step 02 I didn't. I added it now and it was without the line of code! Thanks again!

Comment: Really ans are acceptable..thanks @Raja..

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add Appearance key with value Light in your Info.plist

[Please check this image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryxwf.png)