# iOS15 UINavigationBarAppearance hide battery / time icons (UIStatusBarStyle)

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar, ios15

On iOS15 I was no longer able to set as black

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(hexString: "#000000")
UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
```

I've fixed that with change

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
appearance.backgroundColor = .black
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance;
UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance;
```

but now I have a problem with missing battery / clock icons

[image: Not working iOS15]

[image: Working iOS13]

Comment: This one might be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68600926/14733292

Comment: Hi Raja, option with settings UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to false and set UIStatusBarStyle for all viewcontrollers worked for me. If you write that as answer I will mark it as fix. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change status bar style from the `info.plist`

1: Set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to false

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
```

2: Add Status bar style key and set style like Light Content

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `UINavigationController` override `preferredStatusBarStyle` and return `.lightContent`

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awful... the status bar style color... 

I've been fighting with this issue for years, different rules based on plist, overrides, navigationVC, changing styles or overridding styles based in iOS version, or overriding the whole app? dark mode ....  

oh god, 
now i will attempt to have a class UINavigationControllerLight and UINavigationControllerDark...  
so much trouble just to pick a color... 1 or 0 
it shouldn't be this complex